# I killed your entire family, but you still love me

Tags: riddle

I am what they cherish,

Those who cherish,

Are also those who detest ardently.

I murder with ease and comfort,

And be loved with purpose.

I am a drug to the eye,

And to the heart,

You love me like nobody else,

Not because I murdered your loved ones,

But because I am a drug to the eye,

And to the heart.

I cause no disease,

But yet I abolish those who you love,

For I am a drug to the eye,

And to the heart!

**What am I?**

Hint #1:

> I have a physical existence.

Hint #2:

> I am everywhere.

Comment: Is it "Human Beings"?

Comment: So how does this work, is the answer ever revelled? Or will OP say if someone gets it correct or what?

Comment: I was thinking about fastfood until I read "I cause no disease".

Comment: Do you know something about my family that I don't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's my best guess but I'm not 100%...

> Water

Murder with ease and comfort:

> Drowning is arguably a peaceful way to go.

Loved with purpose:

> I assume this means you love it for its purpose; that is, to quench your thirst. For which it is definitely loved!

Drug to the eye:

> Eyedrops!

And to the heart:

> Possibly an IV, this is definitely the most tenuous link of the lot.

It is certainly cherished in some forms, but detested in others.

> Fresh, drinking water vs. Sea water, rain, etc.?

And it certainly causes no diseases. Plus has a physical existence and is pretty much everywhere, as the hints direct.

Comment: I wouldn't describe drowning as "peaceful"... I'm now thinking along the same line, though, as it must be something nigh ubiquitous like time, water, oxygen, etc.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why this is the accepted answer. It doesn't fit the title.

Answer (score 13):

I think the answer is:

> **TIME**

---

Are also those who detest ardently.

> Some people hate how little time they have

I murder with ease and comfort,

> Time kills all slowly without pain

I am a drug to the eye,

> People always look at the time numerous times of the day. (also people who clock watch while at work etc.)

And to the heart,

> Time can heal a broken heart / People would love to have more time

Comment: kinda makes sense, but how does it fit with the "drug to the eye" ?

Comment: @JLee Because your eyes get tired and desire sleep and it feels sooooooo good.

Comment: @SaturnsEye I'm sure this is right but you should really expand your answer to show how it answers each of the clues although you could probably group together the duplicate lines.

Comment: @JLee because people can't help but look at the time

Comment: @EngineerToast had to rush as i'm at work; updated now

Comment: @SaturnsEye, I think the heart reference may be referring to time healing broken hearts.

Comment: @IanMacDonald ah yes, of course. I've edited my answer to include that also

Comment: A very clever try but that isn't it, unfortunately.

Comment: TIME doesn't have physical existence.

Comment: @CoDeMurDeRer the question was changed to add that hint *after* I gave my answer

Comment: I don't think we LOVE time so much :-)

Answer (score 9):

It is

> Money

right?

I murder with ease and comfort,

> if you have more money than life will be easy, cause no disease ,drug to the eye

I am a drug to the eye,
And to the heart.

> Money is drug to eyes, and its feel good in heart if have money

Are also those who detest ardently

> People get jealous if you have more money.

You love me like nobody else

> everyone loves money

Not because I murdered your loved ones,
But because I am a drug to the eye

> Some Peoples kills their loved once due to money, although they love money.

I cause no disease

> of course, it cause no disease

I am a drug to the eye,

And to the heart

> feels good to see money , so we can say its drug of eye and heart.

As per Hint , Money have **physical existence** also.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> Sleeping

Because

> we love sleeping but people may die in their sleep

and

> they die with ease and comfort

and

> it's good for your eye and heart :)

Comment: We can die sleeping, but sleeping does not kill

Answer (score 5):

It was my first impulse when I read medicine to the eye and the heart

> Atropine or the plant that derives it,  Belladonna (Also known as deadly nightshade)

Hear me out.

*I am what they cherish,*

*Those who cherish,*

*Are also those who detest ardently.*

*I murder with ease and comfort,*

> Atropine is a potent toxin in high doses

*And be loved with purpose.*

> in medicinal doses it is an important medicine, it's on the [WHO Model list of essential medicines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHO_Model_List_of_Essential_Medicines)

*I am a drug to the eye,*

> It was, tho not so much anymore, used for pupil dilation in ophthalmology.

*And to the heart,*

> It is also a treatment for bradycardia (Dangerously low heartrate)

*You love me like nobody else,*

*Not because I murdered your loved ones,*

*But because I am a drug to the eye,*

> Belladonna at a recreational dose is a hallucinogenic. It can be consumed by squeezing the berries into your eye.

*and to the heart.*

> It has been used in the past as a cosmetic (love/attraction),

*I cause no disease,*

> it doesn't

*but yet I abolish those who you love,*

> but it's still poisonous, and may kill those using it haphazardly as a  cosmetic.

*For I am a drug to the eye,*

*and to the heart!*

> lost loved (and beautiful) ones.

As for the hints, this is definitely a physical thing, and (plants in the family producing it) can be found everywhere (except Antarctica)

> As a warning to anyone who may not have been aware of this before, the experience recreationally is usually reported as unpleasant, and the difference between a recreational dose and a fatal dose is scary close. Don't be an idiot.

Comment: Sounds promising. "You love me like nobody else" seems like a rather odd line to me though.

Comment: It would be even better if in some lines we'll take the answer not as a drug or as a plant, but translating the word directly as a beautiful girl. The line about murdering the family is formulated so, that could be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is

> CO2 / Carbon dioxide

I am what they cherish,

> We all intake CO2

Those who cherish,

Are also those who detest ardently.

> We breathe it out

I murder with ease and comfort,

> CO2 can kill

And be loved with purpose.

I am a drug to the eye,

And to the heart,

> Here it refers to CO2 Laser used to do surgical operations on Eyes and Heart

You love me like nobody else,
Not because I murdered your loved ones,
But because I am a drug to the eye,
and to the heart.

I cause no disease,
but yet I abolish those who you love,
For I am a drug to the eye,
and to the heart!

> Again a reference to CO2 laser and CO2

Comment: "Are also those who detest ardently." - Could refer to climate change advocates. "And be loved with purpose" - Plants need it. 

I like this answer

Answer (score 1):

> PROPAGANDA alters the way you see and feel (like a drug) and can kill loved ones who speak out (indirectly) without causing disease. Those who cherish the words of a corrupt power are the ones who detest ardently without thought for why.

Or if the OP is cynical, then

> RELIGION might also fit the bill because of the historical precedence of violence in the name of love. The imagery associated with religion include cherished symbols (like the cross in Christianity) that act like drugs for the eye and heart, inciting rage and violence in some and love and grace in others.

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like (perhaps a cynical view of)

> BEAUTY.

*I am what they cherish,*

> Certainly many people cherish beauty.

*Those who cherish,*

*Are also those who detest ardently.*

> Refers to the complicated nature of emotions - "love-hate relationships" and so on.

*I murder with ease and comfort,*

*And be loved with purpose.*

> I can't quite parse these lines. The second of them sounds like an imperative, but the sentence structure suggests it's indicative - in which case shouldn't it be "am" and not "be"?

*I am a drug to the eye,*

*And to the heart,*

> These lines are what put me onto this solution. Beauty is something your eyes desire, and it can entrap your heart too, despite being - at the end of the day - quite superficial.

*You love me like nobody else,*

> People fall in love for the sake of beauty.

*Not because I murdered your loved ones,*

> Refers to the fact that beauty fades with time; if you love someone only for their looks, then they might eventually stop being your "loved one".

*But because I am a drug to the eye,*

*and to the heart.*

> See above.

*I cause no disease,*

> True.

*but yet I abolish those who you love,*

> Again, see above.

*For I am a drug to the eye,*

*and to the heart!*

> Again, see above!

This answer just about fits Hint 1, because although it's an abstract concept in itself and not something physical, it does *describe* something physically visible. And as for Hint 2, it's everywhere for those with eyes to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> The Earth / dirt / land

*I am what they cherish,*

> Many tribes do.

*Those who cherish,


Are also those who detest ardently.*

> People are poising the Earth

*I murder with ease and comfort,


And be loved with purpose.*

> People are buried in the Earth

*I am a drug to the eye,


And to the heart,*

> The nature on Earth is the most beautiful thing isn't it?

*You love me like nobody else,*

> That's true.

*Not because I murdered your loved ones,


But because I am a drug to the eye,


and to the heart.*

> The Earth is just lovely

*I cause no disease,


but yet I abolish those who you love,


For I am a drug to the eye,


and to the heart!*

> This is just a fill

Comment: Satisfies the hints too, It is physical, and it is everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking something along the lines of:

> **war**
>
> It is the drug to the eye as people love to watch war, humans have always been fascinate by it.
>
> The ease and comfort more so is a reflection of the fact that war kills swiftly and with no resistance.
>
> It causes no disease, and it indeed is almost everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please could you edit in an explanation as to why you think this answer fits the question? Answers without explanation often get downvoted and even deleted.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for the information. Can you let me know if my answer shows up as a spoiler as intended? I cannot see it as such

Comment: @LearningMath To make text show up as a spoilerblock, you need to start with ">!" on a new line (inline spoilers have been requested as a new feature IIRC but not implemented). To spoilerblock more than one paragraph, you need to put ">!" before each blank line between as well. I learnt all this the hard way! Hopefully my telling you this will be more useful than simply editing your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think the answer could be

> a love one

because

> everyone is capable of love, but not everyone have that someone to love. and not all but some of those lonely hearts just detest anything love related.

I murder with ease and comfort,

> some people just get mad when they're in love, and commit serious crimes

I am a drug to the eye

> seeing that love one can be just like a drug

Not because I murdered your loved ones,

> not necessarly means that she or he just killed your family, it's just that your feellings for her or him are too strong making your family to dissapear.

I am everywhere.

> the love of your life could be in anyplace, anytime, everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

My guess

> Fat (Fatty food)

I am what they cherish,

Those who cherish,

> People love fatty food for its taste

Are also those who detest ardently.

> Those who understand the ill-effects also cherish

I murder with ease and comfort,

> It kills slowly

And be loved with purpose.

I am a drug to the eye,

> Fat-rich food looks/tastes good

And to the heart,

> Good Fat(LDL) is a drug to heart

You love me like nobody else,

Not because I murdered your loved ones,

But because I am a drug to the eye,

and to the heart.

I cause no disease,

but yet I abolish those who you love,

> Fat itself doesn't cause any disease, but causes other diseases, which are dangerous

For I am a drug to the eye,

and to the heart!

Answer (score 0):

My first post here, excuse me for any errors.

Is it:

> Contact?

*I am what they cherish,*

*Those who cherish,*

> Those who love you, hold you and hug you provide contact.

*Are also those who detest ardently.*

*I murder with ease and comfort,*

> Murder also involves contact, a hug of death, or a pillow over a face.

*And be loved with purpose.*

*I am a drug to the eye,*

> The physical object contact is a drug to the eye, you need it to see.

*And to the heart,*

> Again, contact in a loving manner is a drug for the heart.

*You love me like nobody else,*

*Not because I murdered your loved ones,*

*But because I am a drug to the eye,*

*and to the heart.*

*I cause no disease,*

> Although killing by contact does not involve disease, it can cause it, I'm not sure about this.

*but yet I abolish those who you love,*

> Contact can be used to kill and love.

*For I am a drug to the eye,*

*and to the heart!*

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie, so I may be way off:

> Beauty?

Re: to those who detest....

> Because beauty is both lovely and a curse to those without it or if it's only superficial ("beauty is only skin deep/beauty is as beauty does").  It "murders" with ease and comfort as it is a disguise many times for things lethal but pleasant to the eye or heart, and easily and comfortable because beautiful people or things are typically more entitled due to their appeal and therefore have an ease while operating or in motion; comfortable in one's own skin?  And the eye and heart appeal is simply that beauty to our eyes actually makes our pupils dilate when we glance at things our eyes find pleasant or beautiful, and the heart is effected by beauty in emotion and we embrace the beauty of things/people more easily than things that are unappealing or ugly in a physical sense.

How'd I do?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'm afraid the correct answer was already found three years ago, and you are indeed way off. Nice try, though! In future, please hide your answers using spoiler tags (type `>!` at the start of a paragraph) to avoid spoiling your solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves.